# Find points inside the intersection of polygons in PostgreSQL/PostGIS is too slow

Tags: postgresql, postgis, psycopg2, postgresql-9.4

I have written some code in psycopg2 that calculates the points inside the intersection of two polygons in PostgreSQL/PostGIS.

The code that I am using:

```
    for i in range(len(linesreplace) - 1):
        intersect = """select 
                   ST_Contains(
                       ST_Intersection(
                           ST_GeometryFromText('SRID=4326; POLYGON((10.9204102 40.2292182,10.5688477 36.4389612,14.3041992 36.4389612,13.4033203 40.2627607,10.9204102 40.2292182))'),
                           ST_MakeValid(
                               ST_GeometryFromText('SRID=4326; POLYGON((8.503418 39.1300602,8.2177734 36.8620427,15.4467773 36.9323301,15.1391602 39.1811753,8.503418 39.1300602))')
                           )
                       ),
                       the_geom
                   ),
                   vessel_hash,
                   the_geom
               from samplecol as col WHERE col.timestamp > """ + linesreplace[i] + """ and col.timestamp < """ + \
                    linesreplace[i + 1]

        cursor.execute(intersect)
        pointsINtw = cursor.fetchall()
```

The code works fine but the execution time is too slow. Does anyone know how to speed up the query?

Comment: Sidenote: `WHERE col.timestamp > """ + linesreplace[i] + """ ` => It should be parameterized. String concatentation could lead to SQL Injection

Comment: Hi Lukasz. What do you mean? I use timestamps from a list with timestamps.

Comment: Any kind of string concatenation/interpolation when it should be avoided.  [Python MySQL Execute Parameterized Query using Prepared Statement](https://pynative.com/python-mysql-execute-parameterized-query-using-prepared-statement/) but idea is the same for PostgreSQL

Comment: So as I can see I will add cursor = connection.cursor(prepared=True) in order to speed up the query. I would appreciated If you can add an example.

Comment: @Telperinquar, could you please show EXPLAIN of your query? Just put EXPLAIN in front of a query, execute it and show the output. This will show how the query planner is going to execute this query.

Also, could you please make sure you have a GIST index on `samplecol` table?